# Is the phrase "like a fish in water" a valid English phrase meaning feel comfortable in a certain place?

Tags: idioms

Could you tell me if the phrase *like a fish in water* is a valid English phrase meaning feel comfortable in a certain place? For example:

> Mike is like **a fish in water** when he is abroad.

If it's not, then what is the valid phrase to convey the meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly I've only ever heard *like a fish **out of** water* used to describe someone who's **not** comfortable in a situation. I suppose you could use the opposite and hope people understand the contrast you're making, but "a fish in water" is the normal, usual, non-notable state of things, so it might not be clear what you're implying.

*Mike is **in his element** when he is abroad* is one idiom you can use, there are probably a lot more! *Happy as a pig in mud* if you want an animal metaphor?

Comment: There is also "like a duck to water", but that more often follows 'takes': Mike takes to travel(ling) like a a duck to water.

Comment: @Sydney oh yeah, I think that's a better fit for the tone! t's more like "he's comfortable and handles things well" instead of just "he's happy and enjoying himself"