What is the English expression saying a person is in a very good environment that helps him to make the most of his ability?
Say, Bob graduated from university with a degree in computer science. He found a job in a company. They put him in the software department and he couldn't do his job well because he was better at hardware than software (situation 2). Now he really loved his job.
In the second situation, Vietnamese people say "he was like a fish meeting water" (literally translated from Vietnamese)?
Is there a similar expression in English?
I noticed English has the phrase "to be like a fish out of water".
Can we say "he was like a fish out of water" for the first situation and "he was like a fish in water" for the second one because the opposite of "out of" is "in"?
Do we have other expressions to express the situation 1 and 2?
For example, "he took to the hardware department like a duck to water".
What is the English expression saying a person is in a very good environment that helps him to make the most of his ability?

he blossomed in hardware department ... he found his niche ... he found his calling

Someone else will point this out and explain better than I can, but, I believe being a software developer or engineer and being a hardware engineer are two very distinct fields, perhaps, incompatible with one another. But I understand what you are getting at, the person felt more confident and was better suited to the latter role than the former.

See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/270847/is-the-phrase-like-a-fish-in-water-a-valid-english-phrase-meaning-feel-comfort  that might be close enough to count as a duplicate.

It suggests "in his element", or if starting out "like a duck  to water"

Perhaps he fell on his feet, especially if he found the good environment by luck.

One possibility is He's in his happy place

@Mari-LouA  Off topic, but I started out as an electronic R&D engineer (hardware) and migrated to a software engineer over the years, finally with IBM. Now retired, I still dabble in both. In my time I've worked with an ex-monk, an aerodynamics graduate, two physicist PhDs and several other disciplines. Don't forget, 50-60 years ago there was no such thing as software engineering as a separate degree subject, the EEs and mathematicians  had to write their own.

@Mari-LouA At one of the most prestigious technical institutions in the world, EE and CS are part of the same department. Students specialize in one or the other, but are required to take several classes from the other side.

x graduated with a degree in computer science.

"A fish in water" is a valid idiom, although it is not used anywhere near as often as its reverse, "a fish out of water", that you mentioned.
More common expressions include:

he is in his element
he found his niche
he is where he belongs

Other expressions that focus more on a person being happy where they are include:

he's like a kid in a candy store
he's like a pig in muck (or sometimes a cruder term)

There are countless other expressions but I've tried to focus on ones which refer to a person being in a place, similar to "a fish in water".

like a pig in the mud, surely? or shit, but still.

"kid in a candy store[/shop]" I've mostly heard being used as "being excited from having a lot of options to choose from."

Also “It’s in his wheelhouse”
